# Ionic 2 manual reload to get Data

Tags: woocommerce, ionic2

I am using a service to fetch the products from `woocommerce`. In the constructor of the service, I make an HTTP get call which fetches products and subscribe to the local data variable.Then I created a function `getData()` in the service which returns this fetched data to `myPage`. Then from `myPage`, I make a call to the `getData()` function from the constructor of my Component page and assign it to the local products array. 
The problem is that when my page gets loaded initially the data is not yet received/subscribed by the HTTP get call inside my service constructor so the `getData()` function call returns null array and I have to reload the component page manually after the data have been received in the service to get the data in my page.

Any idea what I am doing wrong here? and possible solution for that. 
Thanks.

Here is my code.

```
 Service is fetching data from woocommerce.


 constructor(public http: Http) {
 console.log("itemservice constructor called")
 this.http.get(`${this.producturl}`).map(res=><Product[]>res.json()).subscribe(prods =>{
    console.log("inside subscribe");
    this.items=prods;
  });
  getData(){
     return this.items;
  }
```

Code for page which is calling getData()

```
constructor(public nav: NavController, public categoryService: 
CategoryService, public itemService: ItemService, public loadingCtrl: 
LoadingController) 
{
    console.log("home page constructor");
    this.items = this.itemService.getData();
}
```

Comment: code speaks better than words. And it would be easy to suggest solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description, it looks like you really can get the data from your service, although I am not sure why you put the logic in the constructor, it looks like you missed some basic idea about Angular, it is all about data binding, therefore your Page/Component should be binded to that data observable, and will be auto "updated" when the data is fetched.

Not sure about your intent, but I however will do it this way, and most important part is however the View, note:never tested

```
 constructor(public http: Http) {
 console.log("itemservice constructor called")
  }

  getData(){
 this.http.get(`${this.producturl}`).map(res=><Product[]>res.json()).subscribe(prods =>{
    console.log("inside subscribe");
    this.items=prods;
  });
```

Code for page which is calling getData()

```
    constructor(public nav: NavController, public categoryService: 
    CategoryService, public itemService: ItemService, public loadingCtrl: 
    LoadingController) 
    {
 this.itemService.getData();
    }
```

View:

```
<div  *ngFor="let item of itemService.items"  >

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have added the code please take a look.

Comment: I get it what you were saying. I should subscribe to my page rather than service.